# Git multi-master, is it possible?

Tags: replication, git, scm

Is it possible to set a **dual master GIT repositories**?
I would like to set up two different servers which I could push and commit to and changes on any of them would be propagated to the other.

I've googled for it, but the most similar solution I've found is [Gerrit2](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn/documentation/2.1.2/config-replication.html), but it does only one way replication (master -> master).

Does anybody know if this is even possible to do with git? If so, could you please tell me which tools to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could begin creating a solution yourself using post-commit hooks, but that's more of a stackoverflow thing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll take a look at that hooks thing.